# Python avoiding using for loop or need shorten the code base

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have write python code and it has too many for loop, as a result, my code readability is too low and pylint star too low.

I am finding a way to solve same with fewer line of code.

here you go for my snippet:

```
numberlist = [1,3,5]
stringlist = ['a', 'b', 'c']
id = '458'

numbered_string = []
for n, s in numberlist, stringlist:
    num_str = "{}{}".format(
                n,
                s,
                id,
            )
    numbered_string.append(num_str)

codes = []
for n,s, sn in numberlist, stringlist, numbered_string:
    code = make_code(
        n,
        s,
        sn
    )
    codes.append(code)

print(codes)
```

Ignore the function `make_code()` , or let's assume the `make_code()` is

```
def make_code(n,s, sn):
    return str(n) + str(s) + str(sn)
```

Can anyone help me shorten the snippet?, please ignore the function. I want to improve this code much better and high readability, too many instance is not a solution.

Comment: Hi there. Could you provide an example of what you expect `numbered_string` to contain? Because as is, your code gives an error at `for n, s in numberlist, stringlist:` (should be zipped?)

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at **list comprehensions**. So, instead of:

```py
codes = []
for n, s, sn in zip(numberlist, stringlist, numbered_string):
    code = make_code(
        n,
        s,
        sn
    )
    codes.append(code)
```

you can write:

```py
codes = [make_code(n, x, sn) for n, x, sn in zip(numberlist, stringlist, numbered_string)]
```

Note that I used `zip(numberlist, stringlist, numbered_string)` in the `for` statement instead of the bare `numberlist, stringlist, numbered_string`.  At least for me, on python 3.6, the latter does not work.

List comprehensions (and relatives for sets, dictionaries, generators, etc.) are super useful, and have lots of features, such as filtering using an `if` clause after the `for` clause, and supporting nested loops.

If your goal is to improve the readability of your code, you might want to also make sure your spacing is consistent (e.g. `n, s, sn` instead of `n,s, sn`) and your naming of variables is consistent -- in general, in python, variables and functions should be written in `snake_case`(e.g. `number_list` instead of `numberlist`).